# Plotting multiple .TIFF images together with individual titles in R

Tags: r, plot, raster, tiff

I would like to plot multiple .TIFF images in R and add individual titles to them. Without the titles, this piece of code gets the job done:

```
require(raster)

setwd("...")
files = list.files(pattern="*.tif")

tiff("balanded_1.tiff", units="in", width=21, height=26, res=300, compression = 'lzw') #for saving

par(mfrow=c(5,3)) 

for (i in 1:15) {
  plotRGB(brick(files[i]))
}

dev.off() #save figure
```

However, if I try to add individual titles to the images using 'plotRGB()', it automatically adds axes to them (because 'axes=TRUE' becomes a requirement in the ['plotRGB()' function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.3-7/topics/plotRGB)), and I get something like this:

```
plotRGB(brick(files[2]), axes=TRUE, main="TITLE", xlab="", ylab="")
```

[image]

I understand that 'plotRGB()' is probably not the right function for the job (since I am not plotting maps), but I wonder if there is a way to make it work? If not, is there an alternative I could use? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this problem using a more appropriate package for image manipulation:

```
require(magick)

setwd("...")
files = list.files(pattern="*.tif")

tiff("balanded_1.tiff", units="in", width=21, height=26, res=300, compression = 'lzw')
par(mfrow=c(5,3)) 
for (i in 1:15) {
  name <- files[i] 
  lag <- strsplit(name, "_")[[1]][2] #get the name right for the image
  match <- strsplit(name, "_")[[1]][4]
  lead <- strsplit(name, "_")[[1]][6]
  lead <- strsplit(lead, ".tiff")[[1]][1]
  name <- paste("   Lag=",lag,", Match=1:",match,", Lead=",lead, sep = "") #put the name together
  img <- image_annotate(image_read(files[i]), name, font = 'Times', size = 120) #read the image and add the name
  img <- image_crop(img, "1500x1050")
  plot(img) 
}
dev.off() #save figure
```